# Effect space-between with css grid

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

How can I achieve the "space-between" effect of Flexbox with CSS Grid?

You can see my code in the following link:

[Codepen - Flexbox and Css Grid](https://codepen.io/jjreina/pen/ZEqPwMW)

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-items: center;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: lightcyan;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Css Grid</h1>
<section class="grid-container">
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
</section>
<h1>Flexbox</h1>
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
</section>
```

I have explained myself wrong, what I want to achieve is the second image using css grid

[image]

Thanks

Comment: `repeat(3, 1fr)` means "*make this grid have 3 columns of equal width*", and therefore each column will as wide as a third of the grid (no space remain). Replace `1fr` with `min-content` or similar if you need `justify-content: space-between` to work.

Answer (score 0):

**To make the effect of Flexbox with CSS Grid:**
This is not a standard grid thing and flexbox would be the obvious solution. However, you can achieve this by changing the properties of the grid elements:

```
.box {
  margin: auto; // changed from 10px to auto
}

.box:first-child {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.box:last-child {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

This will ensure the first and last elements are next to the edges and the margins will grow in the center.

**To make the effect of Grid with Flexbox:**
Just change this property in your flex container:
`justify-content: space-between;` to this: `justify-content: space-around;`
They are quite self descriptive. I think it doesn't need extra information.

An easy way to play around with this is using a browser inspector tool.

Comment: You miss the question. The question is not how to use spac-earound in flexbox but how to achieve a space-between behavior in grid

Comment: I apologize for the misunderstanding. I want CSS Grid looks the same as Flexbox,

Comment: Since I started this, I went all the way and corrected my answer. Let me know if it's what you expected.

Comment: @JuanReinaPascual let me know if this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `margin:10px auto;` on `.flex-container .box`.

After if you want to create a 3 columns, grid you will need to add extra CSS as in below demo:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /***** ADDED *****/
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.flex-container .box{ /***** ADDED *****/
  margin:10px calc(16.5% - 60px);
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width:120px;
}
```

### DEMO

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-items: center;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*justify-content: space-between;*/
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.flex-container .box{ /***** ADDED *****/
  margin:10px calc(16.5% - 60px);
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width:120px;
}

.box{
  margin:10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width:120px;
  height:120px;
  background-color: lightcyan;
  text-align: center;
  line-height:120px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Css Grid</h1>
<section class="grid-container">
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box">Box 4</div>
</section>
<h1>Flexbox</h1>
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
  <div class="box">Box 4</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use `1fr`, use `auto`

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: lightcyan;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Css Grid</h1>
<section class="grid-container">
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
</section>
<h1>Flexbox</h1>
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="box">Box 1</div>
  <div class="box">Box 2</div>
  <div class="box">Box 3</div>
</section>
```